# Saving Captured Images using javascript on intel XDK

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I'm trying to make an app which accesses the camera and captures images. The problem is I'm not able to save it. I'm pretty new to javascript and have been tweaking the code snippets provided by intel. I'm using the intel XDK new. Here's my code.

```
function capturePhoto() {
  AppMobi.camera.takePicture(50,true,"jpg");
}

function onSuccess(evt) {

  if (evt.success == true)
  {
    // create image 
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src=AppMobi.camera.getPictureURL(evt.filename);
    image.id=evt.filename;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
  }

}
```

I'm able to capture the image but I'm not able to store it on my device inspite of changing the boolean value in the function to true.

Answer (score 4):

not sure why you have `image.id=evt.filename;`, try this code:

```
function xdkStartCamera() {
    var onSuccess = function(event) {
        if (event.success == true){
            $('#xdk-camera-image').html("<img src="+intel.xdk.camera.getPictureURL(event.filename)+" width='250' />");
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.add", onSuccess); 
    intel.xdk.camera.takePicture (70, true, "jpg");
}
```

full code here, try in xdk: http://jsbin.com/eDOKIDiB/1/edit

Comment: Worked, many thanks, I had to change the line that assigns the img src though: $('#xdk-camera-image').attr("src", intel.xdk.camera.getPictureURL(event.filename));